# Install multiple release branches of a single web site into IIS

Tags: iis, branch, ports

I'm branching a new release branch in SVN for every candidate release. Ex: 3.1, 3.2, 4.1, etc.

Then I want to deploy all branches into the same server independently, because several developers might need to work on different release candidates at the same time.

So we deploy the different web sites into different ports. Ex: 8031 for 3.1, 8032 for 3.2, 8041 for 4.1, etc.

Is this a best practice or there is a better practice to achieve this?

**Edit:** How to achieve this for a WCF Web Site using MSMQ, since it uses at least 4 bindings for a single web site (4 bindings: http:*:80:,net.msmq:localhost,net.tcp:808:*,net.pipe:*,msmq.formatname:localhost)?

Thanks,
Miguel

Answer (score 1):

Why not create a new directory for each branch within IIS? You could use these directory names in your WCF endpoints so the branches do not conflict with eachother. For net.tcp you should probably use port sharing if you want all branches listening on the same port. I'm not sure if this will working for msmq.

Comment: For msmq we would need to create different queues for different branches, by suffixing the queue name with the branch number. I'm not sure if we can do that with NServiceBus (yes we are using NServiceBus).

Comment: You can do this with NServiceBus, see [this link for code)[https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/endpoints/specify-endpoint-name], you can do the same using app.config